# Handling with array of structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Sorry for long question but I am about to go crazy here.

I am trying to write a little simulation of a social network in c language.

I'm trying to create an array of structures which each one is a user.

For 6 days, I'm trying to write the part that the program adding users and reaching the logs afterwards, and I couldn't. So I'm about to lose my mind over here.

```
struct myStruct { /* This is a global variable */
     char *studentName;
    int *bornYear;
    char *school;
};
```

then in the main function, I create a pointer such as;

```
struct myStruct** students = malloc (sizeof(struct myStruct ));
int counter = 0; /* the counter of students */
```

by if-else if and switch-case chains, I categorize the commands. when it is asked to add a new user, a realloc the array I created:

```
students = realloc(students, (counter+1) * sizeof (struct students));
students[counter] = adding (*command, counter);
counter++;
```

the function is here:

```
struct myStruct adding (char theCommand[], int i){
    struct myStruct *q = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct *)); // I get a warning for this allocation
    char *irrelevantChar = strtok(theCommand[], ";");
    q->studentName  = strtok(NULL, ",");
    q->bornYear= strtok(NULL, ",");
    q->school= strtok(NULL, ",");
    return q;
```

I am sure that strtok functions are working right.

When I try to reach these structures, the program gives error on run-time (stoppes working on windows, segmentation fault on ubuntu) or I see random irrelevant data etc. I am working with this for 6 days so I have seen lots of errors. But I couldn't find the right way to create and access these structures.

In another command situation;

```
"command character" John Smith,George Lucas // names are just for example :)
```

I just wrote the following code for this situation:

```
printf ("\n\n%s", myStruct[0]->school;
```

This is just a random order, just to show that I cannot access it.

The output must be "Oxford University" or something. Instead, I get the exactly following output:

```
ge Lucas
```

So some random data. I don't know what is wrong with here either.

I must build friendships etc. so I must have access to every single structure I created.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a specific question you have?

Comment: clicked 'submit' accidentally before finishing the question.

Comment: instead of `struct myStruct *q = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct *));`, you should use `struct myStruct *q = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));`. I would suggest to use a linked list instead of reallocating everytime.

Comment: I should build friendships etc and I get commands by student names, and I use strucure names for lists of friendships. so linked lists may be difficult to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct myStruct {
    char *studentName;
    int bornYear;
    char *school;
} Student;


Student adding (char theCommand[]){
    struct myStruct q;
    char *irrelevantChar = strtok(theCommand, ";");
    q.studentName  = strdup(strtok(NULL, ","));
    q.bornYear= atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
    q.school= strdup(strtok(NULL, ","));
    return q;
}

int main(void){
    char command[] = "junk;George Lucas,1944,University of Southern California";
    int counter = 0;
    Student *students = NULL;
    students = realloc(students, (counter+1) * sizeof (Student));
    students[counter++] = adding(command);

    printf("name   : %s\n", students[0].studentName);
    printf("school : %s\n", students[0].school);

    //deallocation:studentName, school
    //free(students);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
char *strdup(const char *str){
    char *p = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    if(p){
        strcpy(p, str);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with strdup and atoi functions and I'm trying to write in ansi standards, are strdup and atoi functions are ansi standards?

Comment: @user3108849 atoi is present in the standard. strdup does not exist.

Comment: only one final question, what I can replace strdup with in ansi standards? I can't get the results without it.

Comment: @user3108849 I have added a definition of strdup.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the following line allocates enough memory for a *pointer* to `myStruct`, not actually memory for the structure.

```
struct myStruct *q = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct *));
```

You then start to dereference that pointer, so you are accessing unallocated memory at this point:

```
q->studentName  = strtok(NULL, ",");
q->bornYear= strtok(NULL, ",");
q->school= strtok(NULL, ",");
```

I can't say there aren't other bugs in your code, but you need to start by allocating sufficient memory. i.e. `sizeof(struct myStruct)`  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This solves the allocating problem but I still have problems with reaching it.

Comment: I don't know what "reaching it" means. Is your program crashing? At what line?

Comment: You are right. I should have been explained it before. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, the problem seems to be with these blocks of code:

```
struct myStruct **students = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
```

and:

```
students = realloc(students, (counter+1) * sizeof (struct students));
students[counter] = adding (*command, counter);
counter++;
```

You are telling `malloc` to allocate to `students` the amount of space equal to the size of `struct myStruct` but that's probably not what you want because it seems you want students to be an array of `pointers` to `struct myStruct` objects. Thus you need to something along the lines of `struct myStruct **students = malloc(N * sizeof(struct myStruct *));` where `N` is something you choose.

Then your code can go about looking like this:

```
struct myStruct **students = malloc(N * sizeof(struct myStruct *));
int counter = 0;
    .
    .
    .
students[counter] = adding(*command /* Make sure command isn't already a char* */, counter);
counter++;
```

Since you are doing a `malloc` in `adding` and returning the pointer to the malloc'ed space you do not need realloc.

Answer (score 1):

As @Darren has pointed out, you are using heap incorrectly.

Another error in your code is: `struct myStruct** students = malloc (sizeof(struct myStruct ));`

Now either students should be of type `struct myStruct *` or malloc should be called with `sizeof(struct myStruct *)`. Based on your later code for adding using realloc, I deem that it is the former.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to use an int pointer for the "bornYear"?

change to

```
struct myStruct { /* This is a global variable */
    char  *studentName;
    int   bornYear;
    char  *school;
};
```

You probably also want to explicitly specify the length of the char* arrays e.g,

`char[40] studentName`

Hence

```
struct myStruct { /* This is a global variable */
    char    studentName[40];
    int     bornYear;
    char    school[80];
};
```

You could leave school and studentName as a char pointer (char*) but by doing so you all you have within the struct is not the string itself but a pointer to a memory location outside the struct that you will need dynamically allocate in the heap using malloc and manipulate using the standard c string manipulation functions like strcpy etc.

By declaring the struct with a char array (otherwise known as a string), you do simplify the whole process and effectively keep the string within the struct but can potentially run into two issues:

1. There is potential for exceeding the size of the assigned array if your string is greater than the char[n - 1] (n - 1 due to the string terminating nul charcater \0 ), this can be avoided by careful programming.
2. By having to assign a generous length to avoid the above point, you do effectively waste a little space.

Comment: @user3108849 Please also note my discussion of using just the char* instead of a char[]. I edited my original post to reflect this.

Comment: I edited the year thing as normal integers instead of pointers. but when I try to change the name and school pointers to arrays I faced with too many errors so I don't think I can do that. What are the disadvantages of using pointers except dynammic memory allocation ?

Comment: @user3108849 Sorry, probably partly my mistake. You specify the size of the array next to the name not the declaration of the data type, per standard C nomenclature. Corrected above.